# How to install git bash on ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu. Previously I was on Windows and was using `git bash` for `git` commands.
But I have decided to use Ubuntu and I installed `git` but I am not sure whether it is necessary to install `git bash` on Ubuntu? And, if it is necessary, how should I install it?

Comment: You only need `git bash` on Windows because Windows doesn't have its own `bash` shell available. All *NIX have `bash` available so `git bash` isn't needed

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If it's not installed yet:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Check installation:

```
git --version
```

When it's installed, you can use it inside your existing bash in ubuntu.

Comment: What about separate terminal of `git`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh What exactly is your question?

Comment: `git` comes with his own terminal **Git bash** I see no such terminal in ubuntu but I have one in windows once installed

Comment: Git bash only exist for Windows because there was traditionally no bash (or other unix-ish shell) on that OS. In Ubuntu, you may just want to use the standard bash for Git. If you want to customize the prompt similar to Git bash (showing branch etc.), you can google for something like "git bash ps1" for guidance.